# Name of solid geometric figure

Tags: geometry, terminology, euclidean-geometry, solid-geometry

What is the English name of this solid geometric figure?

[image]

I have yet to find the correct English term for it. In Danish it is "kugleudsnit".

[Bonus question:
How could this be derived without using integration, but knowing formulas for volume of cylinder, sphere and cone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298272/derive-proof-volume-of-spherical-sector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [spherical cone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCone.html) seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: The formulas are indeed matching, but is $2R^2$ equivalent to $d^2$? If so, thank you very much.

Comment: $2R = d$, so $d^2 = 4R^2$, which is actually the equality we'd like

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia lists it as a [spherical sector](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector) and Wolfram as a [spherical cone](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCone.html).

Comment: The formulas are indeed matching, but is $2R^2$ equivalent to $d^2$? If so, thank you very much.

Comment: Note that you go from $d^2/6$ in your volume formula to $2R^2/3$ in the Wolfram one (with $\pi$ and $h$ being equal between the two). So actually, it's $d^2=4R^2$, as it should be (since $d=2R$).

Comment: That is right. Are you able to comment on my bonus question or do you think I should create a separate question for that?

Comment: Never mind, I have created [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298272/derive-proof-volume-of-spherical-sector) another one.