# Derive/proof volume of Spherical sector

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation, volume, solid-geometry

How should I derive/proof volume of [Spherical sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_sector) ($V=\frac{2 \pi r^2h}{3}$) without using integration, but knowing formulas for volume of cylinder, sphere and cone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider how much of the surface area is covered by the sector as a fraction of the whole.  The surface area is given by $2 \pi r h$, since this is the area that the cylinder enclosing it would have.  So, the sector covers $\frac{h}{2r}$ of the sphere, and hence has volume $\frac{h}{2r} \cdot \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3 = \frac{2}{3} \pi r^2 h$.

Comment: Where exactly does $\frac{h}{2r}$ come from?

Comment: $\frac{2\pi r h}{4 \pi r^2} = \frac{h}{2r}$